# Union Inside Where

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to accomplish something like that:

```
SELECT QtdEmbarcados.Total FROM QtdEmbarcados, ProgramacaoBarcas
WHERE (
(SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ProgramacaoBarcas.ViagemID, ProgramacaoBarcas.Data, ProgramacaoBarcas.TSFechamento FROM ProgramacaoBarcas
        WHERE CONVERT(DATE, ProgramacaoBarcas.TSFechamento) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
UNION   
    SELECT InsercaoManual.ViagemID, InsercaoManual.Data, InsercaoManual.TSFechamento FROM InsercaoManual
        WHERE CONVERT(DATE, InsercaoManual.TSFechamento) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
) Retorno)
QtdEmbarcados.ViagemID = Retorno.ViagemID AND QtdEmbarcados.Data = Retorno.Data)
```

And example tables:

`QtdEmbarcados`

ViagemId Data    Total

009------41000---10

029------42000---50

A19------42300---40

`ProgramacaoBarcas`

ViagemId Data  TSFechamento

009------41000-10/05/2013

019------42000-NULL

B49------13000-11/05/2013

`InsercaoManual`

ViagemId Data  TSFechamento

009------21000-NULL

0D9------42000-NULL

A19------42300-10/05/2013

Expected Results:

ViagemId Data  Total

009------21000-10

A19------42300-40

Where i want to retrieve some results from a table `X(QtdEmbarcados.Total)` where these results must be within a range that i get from tables A and B (`ViagemID` and `Data`, PKs).
So, i read `QtdEmbarcados`, check if results exists in table `Retorno` (A and B united), and return then.
But i get error in convert line "Incorrect sintax near (".

Any help ?

**Edit:** Just inserted a example. The result a wanna get from `QtdEmbarcados` are rows 1 (exists in table `ProgramacaoBarcas`) and 3 (exists in table `InsercaoManual`).
I thought in union `ProgramacaoBarcas` and `InsercaoManual` (same shema) and in the where clause use those results.

Sorry if a made some crap. I'm new to SQL.

Thanks !

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  Please provide some sample data and expected results to help clarify.

Comment: Your where clause doesn't evaluate to a boolean value, hence the error. Do you mean `WHERE EXISTS ((SELECT *...`? You also need an AND or OR between that subquery and the bit about dates. Or is that part supposed to be the where clause for the subquery?

Comment: There are too many problems with your script to figure out your exact intentions.  Please add `TSFechamento` field to your sample tables (wherever it belongs) and post the **expected result** of your query based on your sample data.

Comment: Updated the `UNION` code, now i think it's correct. TSFechamento is a DATETIME field. I should only bring the results of today.

Comment: I made another change. Removed the `UNION`, leaving only a single `SELECT`, and works. But i need compare the `SELECT` of two tables, not just one. Is there another way to do that ? I can't make it work using `UNION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @curr_date DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT q.Total 
FROM dbo.QtdEmbarcados q
JOIN dbo.ProgramacaoBarcas r ON q.ViagemID = r.ViagemID AND q.Data = r.Data
JOIN (
    SELECT p.ViagemID, p.Data, p.TSFechamento 
    FROM dbo.ProgramacaoBarcas p
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, p.TSFechamento) = @curr_date)

    UNION  

    SELECT i.ViagemID, i.Data, i.TSFechamento 
    FROM dbo.InsercaoManual i
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, i.TSFechamento) = @curr_date) 
) t ON q.ViagemID = t.ViagemID AND q.Data = t.DATA AND ... -- <-- your WHERE clause
```